# druid rollup exclude a long column

Tags: transform, rollup, druid

my Druid version is 0.16.

I have a long column: status_code, it's just represent http response status.

When enable rollup, this column would be aggregated, but I don't want it. Event I create a transform column, add a string prefix to status_code, make a string column. It also will be aggregated as long column.

How can I exclude this column from rollup? Please heeeeeelp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is also useful to make sure that the column is specified as dimension column, and not as metric. Metric columns are fields which are used in aggregation functions, like sum. Dimensions are "fixed" values which can be used in filtering on specific records, and to group by.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Create a new transform column make long column to string column, then add transformed string column manually in "Edit json spec" tab.